# Amazon Athena- Querying columns with numbers stored as string

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

I have a insurance dataset which includes the number of enrollment for each county. However the number of enrollments is stored as a string. How can i query the data for something like "Find the plans which have a enrollment of more than 50". Unfortunately 50 is stored as a string in the dataset so i need to understand how to run my query using athena. Can someone help please

[image]

Comment: Have you tried `SELECT CAST(column AS integer) FROM table`? If that doesn't work, please edit your question to show us a sample of how the data is stored, and also the DDL that was used to create that column.

Comment: I have tried this. "INVALID_CAST_ARGUMENT: Can not cast '800,850.00' to INT" is the error I get. 800,850 is an example value from column A. column A has several values like these but I have to cast them as an integer so I can use logical operators like greater than or equal. Currently the column has values stored as strings

Comment: Well, that's your problem. `800,850.00` isn't a number, so it cannot be interpreted as a number. Is it a separator for thousands, or is it just two numbers with a comma between? Please edit your question to show us a sample of the data in that column, as it is stored in the file.

Comment: I did upload the sample data. I have to write a query where it shows only those rows where the total_submitted_charge_amount is more than 100000.

Comment: 1,035,296.00 was another amount missing from my results.

Comment: Please do not change the basic content of your question, otherwise the answers no longer match the question. Your original question was asking how to convert columns stored as strings, and that's what the answers provide. If you have a different follow-up question, either append it to the existing question or create a new Question.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein If you see the updated query, I did apply the logic explained here but it does not appear to work on other columns stored as string data type. sorry about the change. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59132598/casting-not-working-correctly-in-amazon-athena is the link to the new post

Answer (score 6):

Cast string to floating point number, not integer, and remove commas before cast. Here is an example:

```
with x AS 
    (SELECT '1,800,850.20' AS "value")
SELECT cast(replace(value,',', '') AS REAL)
FROM x
```

Therefore, you should use:

```sql
SELECT
  npi,
  CAST(REPLACE(total_submitted_charge_amount,',', '') AS REAL) AS charge_amount
FROM cmsaggregatepayment2017
WHERE CAST(REPLACE(total_submitted_charge_amount,',', '') > 100000
ORDER BY CAST(REPLACE(total_submitted_charge_amount,',', '') ASC
LIMIT 1000
```

Comment: Queries of this type are not supported (Service: AmazonAthena; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidRequestException; Request ID: c832b6f7-c66c-41b2-8b55-f3004f2f2edc). Below is my query:                                                                            
select npi,cast(replace(total_submitted_charge_amount,',', ''))
from cmsaggregatepayment2017 
order by total_submitted_charge_amount Asc
limit 1000

Comment: @RajParpani I've incorporated your query into the answer. You were missing the `AS REAL` portion.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Look at my updated answer. I am not getting the result i wanted. For some reason Athena is not reading the numbers correctly when i use > or <

Comment: @RajParpani you are using `total_submitted_charge_amount` in where clause, but it is not typecasted to REAL. You could use `with` statement to fix it:
`with datamart as
(SELECT npi,
         ...,
         CAST(REPLACE(total_submitted_charge_amount,
        ',', '') AS REAL) as total_submitted_charge_amount
FROM cmsaggregatepayment2017)
select * from datamart
WHERE total_submitted_charge_amount > '100000'
        AND provider_zipcode='90250'
ORDER BY  total_submitted_charge_amount ASC LIMIT 1000`

Comment: @shuvalov that is the right solution. Thank you so much. Can you please explain though why did my query not work?

Comment: Strings sort differently to numbers. I've updated the answer to include a sample `WHERE`.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein is it correct for Stackoverflow to modify the sense of the answer that belong to another person? This is the first time I see it :-( Usually people used comments for that.

Comment: @nickolay.laptev Thanks for noticing! I wanted to give the original person who answered the question full credit, while improving the answer. The reality is that StackOverflow is actually a wiki where the community is encouraged to improve the quality of Questions and Answers for all future readers. For an excellent overview of this philosophy, see [Jeff Atwood's explanation of how to write a good question](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HRRWDf-xB2Y). It's a great insight into StackOverflow.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein what you call "improving the answer" another person can find "changing its sense and making it different answer"

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I tried the below query adding to what was suggested before:  Please read my updated questions and if you can help me with the why I'm really curious how casting works.

Answer (score 0):

How about the other way around you whole numbers in the query but you want with commas in the results

in the data: 1000

in the results: 1,000 (you want with comma)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).