# Casting not working correctly in Amazon Athena (Presto)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, presto, amazon-athena

I have a doctor license registry dataset which includes the total_submitted_charge_amount for each doctor as well as the number of entitlements with medicare & medicaid . I used the query from the answer suggested below:

```
    with datamart AS 
    (SELECT npi,
         provider_last_name,
         provider_first_name,
         provider_mid_initial,
         provider_address_1,
         provider_address_2,
         provider_city,
         provider_zipcode,
         provider_state_code,
         provider_country_code,
         provider_type,
         number_of_services,

        CASE
        WHEN REPLACE(num_entitlement_medicare_medicaid,',', '') ='' THEN
        null
        ELSE CAST(REPLACE(num_entitlement_medicare_medicaid,',', '') AS DECIMAL)
        END AS medicare_medicaid_entitlement,
        CASE
        WHEN REPLACE(total_submitted_charge_amount,',', '') ='' THEN
        null
        ELSE CAST(REPLACE(num_entitlement_medicare_medicaid,',', '') AS DECIMAL)
        END AS total_submitted_charge_amount
    FROM cmsaggregatepayment2017)
SELECT *
FROM datamart
ORDER BY  total_submitted_charge_amount DESC
```

Unfortunately I get the error

> INVALID_CAST_ARGUMENT: Cannot cast VARCHAR '' to DECIMAL(38, 0)

This query ran against the `aggregatepayment_data_2017` database, unless qualified by the query. Please post the error message on our forum or contact customer support with Query Id: `be01d1e8-dc4d-4c75-a648-428dcb6be3a5`." I have tried Decimal, Real, Big int and nothing works for casting num_entitlement_medicare_medicaid. Below is a screenshot of how the data looks like:

[image]

Can someone please suggest how to rephrase this query?

Comment: A better approach would be to "clean" the data either by creating new input files that do not have commas, or using `CREATE TABLE AS` to create a new table with the commas removed (using the Replace function). Then, you can query from the new table without having to cast/replace anything.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein How would the query be restructured if i follow your approach

Comment: You would first [Create a Table from Query Results (CTAS) - Amazon Athena](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/ctas.html) that includes the `CAST(REPLACE...)` technique as shown in your question, but it would store the result into a new table. Then, you can query from the new table without having to cast/replace because it is already in your desired format. The benefit of this method is that all the subsequent queries are easy to write.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Can you rephrase my query based off what your trying to explain.

Comment: what about `double`?

Comment: @Lamanus I did try that

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Can you please help rephrase this query. I'm more than willing to chat if your open to it

Comment: is there a `null` value? Cannot cast VARCHAR '' to DECIMAL(38, 0) seems indicate a value `''` to Decimal is failed and I suspect that is null not zero.

Comment: @Lamanus There are null values in the database

Comment: @Lamanus  CASE
        WHEN REPLACE(num_entitlement_medicare_medicaid,'[^A-Za-z0-9.]', '') ='' THEN
        null
        ELSE TRY_CAST(REPLACE(num_entitlement_medicare_medicaid,'[^0-9.]', '') AS DECIMAL)
        END AS medicare_medicaid_entitlement, 
        
        CAST(REPLACE(total_submitted_charge_amount, ',', '') AS REAL) AS total_submitted_charge_amount

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are getting error is you have blank value(but it is not null) in the column and we cannot cast varchar '' as decimal. You can probably use case statement. Also as per the data set column num_entitlement_medicare_medicaid has comma ',' in it which you are not replacing.

```
    SELECT npi, 
case
when REPLACE(num_entitlement_medicare_medicaid,'[^A-Za-z0-9.]', '') ='' then null
else CAST(REPLACE(num_entitlement_medicare_medicaid,'[^0-9.]', '') AS DECIMAL)
end as medicare_medicaid_entitlement,
case 
when REPLACE(total_submitted_charge_amount,'[^A-Za-z0-9.]', '') ='' then null
else CAST(REPLACE(total_submitted_charge_amount,'[^0-9.]', '') AS DECIMAL)
end as total_submitted_charge_amount
FROM cmsaggregatepayment2017
```

Comment: I tried what you suggested and updated my query in the question posted above. I am still getting the same error

Comment: I am assuming you have special characters like \n or \t which you cannot see directly. I am updating query to replace special characters except  dot(.)  and alpha numeric chars.

Comment: Just a suggestion get the records for specific column without casting just replace and column value =''  and actual column value.  Then download the result set and try to see the data in some text editor where you can see the special chars also.

Comment: thank you for the suggestion but I have tried running a python script, removing special characters used on the raw data, uploading it on s3. However after the upload is done, Athena does not read the file at all. This is why I used casting in my queries

Answer (score 3):

Instead of putting cast/replace in your queries, you could **convert the data into a new table** with 'clean' data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE clean_table
WITH (format='Parquet', external_location='s3://my_bucket/clean_data/')
AS
SELECT
  npi,
  provider_last_name,
  provider_first_name,
  ...
  CASE WHEN REPLACE(num_entitlement_medicare_medicaid,',', '') ='' THEN null
       ELSE CAST(REPLACE(num_entitlement_medicare_medicaid,',', '') AS DECIMAL)
       END AS medicare_medicaid_entitlement,
  CASE WHEN REPLACE(total_submitted_charge_amount,',', '') ='' THEN null
       ELSE CAST(REPLACE(num_entitlement_medicare_medicaid,',', '') AS DECIMAL)
       END AS total_submitted_charge_amount
  FROM cmsaggregatepayment2017
```

You can the `SELECT ... FROM clean_table` without having to do any conversions.

In data warehousing, this type of process is known as ETL (Extract, Transform, Load). The cleaning process is the 'transform' to convert the data into a more useful format.

See: [CREATE TABLE AS - Amazon Athena](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/create-table-as.html)

Comment: I am getting the error GENERIC_INTERNAL_ERROR: Path is not absolute: s3://test123data. You may need to manually clean the data at location 's3://aws-athena-query-results-785609744360-us-east-1/Unsaved/2019/12/15/tables/03d3cedf-0101-43cb-91fd-cc8070db0e37' before retrying. Athena will not delete data in your account.

Comment: @RajParpani Please create a new Question rather than asking a new question in a Comment.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59348385/how-to-handle-a-generic-internal-error-in-athena

Comment: stackoverflow.com/questions/59348385/…

Comment: This doesn't answer the question about how to do the string transformation, although it correctly recommends executing it at a better place in the job stream.  However, if the OP is having problems with casting, they will have the same issue with the same function when trying it in the "select table as" use case.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to try try_cast() in presto. This version works on coercion. If there is any error it avoids it and moves to the next item.

Documention: https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/conversion.html