# AWS Athena - How to handle GENERIC_INTERNAL_ERROR?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-athena

I have the following query used on one of my datasets in Athena.

```
CREATE TABLE clean_table
WITH (format='Parquet', external_location='s3://test123data') AS
SELECT npi,
         provider_last_name,
         provider_first_name,
        
    CASE
    WHEN REPLACE(num_entitlement_medicare_medicaid,',', '') ='' THEN
    null
    ELSE CAST(REPLACE(num_entitlement_medicare_medicaid,',', '') AS DECIMAL)
    END AS medicare_medicaid_entitlement,
    CASE
    WHEN REPLACE(total_submitted_charge_amount,',', '') ='' THEN
    null
    ELSE CAST(REPLACE(num_entitlement_medicare_medicaid,',', '') AS DECIMAL)
    END AS total_submitted_charge_amount
FROM cmsaggregatepayment2017
```

Unfortunately after I run this query I get an error as below:

> GENERIC_INTERNAL_ERROR: Path is not absolute: s3://test123data. You may need to manually clean the data at location 's3://aws-athena-query-results-785609744360-us-east-1/Unsaved/2019/12/15/tables/03d3cedf-0101-43cb-91fd-cc8070db0e37' before retrying. Athena will not delete data in your account.

Can someone walk me through how to handle this?

What do I have to do on the bucket since it is empty?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that this message is referring to the **Query result location** in which Athena automatically stores the output of your queries.

This is useful for running queries on the results of queries, or for simply having a copy of the query output.

See: [Working with Query Results, Output Files, and Query History - Amazon Athena](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/querying.html)

You can specify a new output location by clicking the **settings** link in the Athena console and then providing a **Query result location** path, such as: `s3://my-bucket/athena-output/`

I'm not sure what is causing your specific error, but make sure you append a trailing `/` to the location. You might also want to create a new bucket for that output.

Comment: INVALID_CAST_ARGUMENT: Cannot cast VARCHAR '' to DECIMAL(38, 0). You may need to manually clean the data at location 's3://test3data/testdata/Unsaved/2019/12/16/tables/54fb68a0-d858-4896-bd38-b0db9e833526' before retrying. Athena will not delete data in your account.

Comment: The `Cannot cast VARCHAR to DECIMAL` error seems related to your other question. Try getting rid of that error first.

Comment: The `cast` error is related to [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59132598/casting-not-working-correctly-in-amazon-athena-presto).

Comment: CASE
        WHEN REPLACE(num_entitlement_medicare_medicaid,'[^A-Za-z0-9.]', '') ='' THEN
        null
        ELSE TRY_CAST(REPLACE(num_entitlement_medicare_medicaid,'[^0-9.]', '') AS DECIMAL)
        END AS medicare_medicaid_entitlement, 
        
        CAST(REPLACE(total_submitted_charge_amount, ',', '') AS REAL) AS total_submitted_charge_amount

Comment: The comment pasted above by me fixed the problem.